# The Id cannot be computed, since the navigation source 'values' cannot be resolved to a known entity set from model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, odata

I am accessing my OData service with following metadata (simplified and obfuscated to the relevant part), this is generated by using `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` :

```
<Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="MyProject.Api.Models">
            <EntityType Name="ValuesContainer">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="values" Type="Collection(MyProject.Api.Models.Value)"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Value">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="value" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="valuesContainerId" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="valuesContainer" Type="MyProject.Api.Models.ValuesContainer">
                    <ReferentialConstraint Property="valuesContainerId" ReferencedProperty="id"/>
                </NavigationProperty>
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        </DataServices>
</Edmx>
```

Some example the output it generates:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5002/v1/odata/$metadata#ValuesContainer(values())",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "2996e6ea-3e72-4b4c-8b3b-b076e34f6dac",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "Hello world",
                    "valuesContainerId": "2996e6ea-3e72-4b4c-8b3b-b076e34f6dac",
                    "id": "3d10fcfa-27a2-4c21-7e01-08d783bf6c40"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to get a `ValuesContainer` via using the `Simple.Odata.Client` I receive the following error:

`Microsoft.OData.ODataException: 'The Id cannot be computed, since the navigation source 'values' cannot be resolved to a known entity set from model.'`

Part where the exception is thrown:

```
namespace Simple.OData.Client.V4.Adapter
{
    public class ResponseReader : ResponseReaderBase
...
private ODataEntryAnnotations CreateAnnotations(ODataResource odataEntry)
        {
            string id = null;
            Uri readLink = null;
            Uri editLink = null;
            if (_session.Adapter.GetMetadata().IsTypeWithId(odataEntry.TypeName))
            {
                try
                {
// Over here my exception occurs, calculating the odataEntry.Id.AbsoluteUri
                    id = odataEntry.Id.AbsoluteUri;
                    readLink = odataEntry.ReadLink;
                    editLink = odataEntry.EditLink;
                }
                catch (ODataException)
                {
/// Yep, the library contains this typo
                    // Ingored
                }
            }

            return new ODataEntryAnnotations
            {
                Id = id,
                TypeName = odataEntry.TypeName,
                ReadLink = readLink,
                EditLink = editLink,
                ETag = odataEntry.ETag,
                MediaResource = CreateAnnotations(odataEntry.MediaResource),
                InstanceAnnotations = odataEntry.InstanceAnnotations,
            };
        }
...
}
```

Is my metadata wrong and/or is there a workaround for this? It's not really required to solve it, but having that many exceptions thrown during runtime causes too much overhead as these are expensive operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, had to add the `Contained` attribute to my Value.

Comment: "Owned" in EF Core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error, I resolved it by setting:

```
MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

on my Client, as I was only doing read-only operations at the time.

Found that answer here: https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/2211

Answer (score 0):

I was plagued by this particular error as well. But setting Contained attribute wasn't an option for us. Posting this in case anyone else ever runs into this.

The problem for me was that the IModelConfiguration declaration for my entity's key was silently failing (due to another config setting that was trying to set up an Action incorrectly).

So based on the error from Echamus' original post:

> The Id cannot be computed, since the navigation source '**values**' cannot be resolved to a known entity set from model

The solution that fixed it for me was making sure the key was defined for the entity type that "**values**" contains (in this case, **Value**ModelConfiguration):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyProject.Api.Models;

namespace MyProject.Api.Configuration.Model_Configurations
{
    public class ValueModelConfiguration : IModelConfiguration
    {
        public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion)
        {
            builder.EntitySet<Value>(nameof(Value)).EntityType.HasKey(v => v.id);
            // other configurations for your entity (e.g. value) may be here
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: **Value** above is whatever entity for the "navigation source" being complained about in the original error)

If you already have this defined, but you have other configurations occurring before/after it, those other configurations may be the problem and may be causing this particular line to fail silently.

Hope that helps save someone some time in the future.